# Difference in execution speed between eclipse and my compiled program

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization

I have a strange problem. I noticed that on operations where there are variable manipulations in for loops with a lot of iteration, there were big differences in terms of execution time between these two situations:

- The program is launched by Eclipse
- The program is launched in terminal with a "java -jar ..."

The same loop takes 1 hour with the terminal and 1 minute under Eclipse! (it is about reading a CSV file and putting the columns in a table)

I specify that my program has these VM parameters:

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes="" -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" -Xms2g -Xmx40g -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

But the problem doesn't come from there I think. To validate this point I proceeded as follows:

1. I went in the VM arguments of the program launcher in Eclipse and checked that they were there
2. I looked at the default JVM used by Eclipse in the general settings and I used this path to launch my program in terminal with this command :
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe" -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes="" -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" -Xms2g -Xmx40g -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" -jar run.jar

Is there anything that can explain this performance difference? I would like to get it back so that my program can run faster.

Comment: I specify that my program does not generate output in the terminal or elsewhere, the variables are simply put in memory

Comment: The Run Configuration dialog has a "Show Command Line" button at the bottom which shows you the exact command Eclipse is using. Eclipse doesn't do anything special when running a Java program.

Comment: You can also look at the properties of the `java.exe` call in the executing stack in the Debug view to know exactly what it launched that JVM with.